# retrieve Last and 3rd to last row in uneven dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a dataframe that looks like the attached picture.

i want to write a function that returns the last entry of each row : `30.35, 76.06, 1.53`

i can do this for each line, but not for the entire dataframe:

`DataFrame.loc[DataFrame[[('Price', 'A')]].last_valid_index()][[('Price', 'A')]][0]`

additionally i want to take the difference of the last two entries per column, and the average of the last two entries per column. The uneven-ness of the dataframe is killing me. also i'm brand new to python.

```
Price
```

Security    A   B   C
Date
12/31/2016  60.5    76.0351 0.83
1/31/2017   59.5    75.7433 -0.01
2/28/2017   63.15   75.7181 0.25
3/31/2017   61.7    76.0605 1.53
4/30/2017   60.35   NaN NaN

Comment: you forgot to attach the picture, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44146136/edit) your question -- but instead of attaching a picture, would you please just copy & paste the dataframe as plain text

Answer (score 0):

To rerun the last entry of each row, you can use list indexing as follows:

```
for i in my_list:    
    variable = my_list[i][-1]  # returns the last variable of row in list my_list
    return variable
```

You can append the concerned variables to other lists, and use list indexing again to compare.